# Find D-Bus unique address using gdbus

Tags: c, linux, dbus, bluez, gdbus

I'm trying to find out the best way to acquire the unique D-Bus address of an object in the D-Bus system bus using the GDBus library on Linux.

Here are version numbers of the libraries I am using:

```
# ls /usr/lib |grep -e dbus -e glib -e gio
libdbus-1.so
libdbus-1.so.3
libdbus-1.so.3.14.11
libdbus-glib-1.so
libdbus-glib-1.so.2
libdbus-glib-1.so.2.3.3
libgio-2.0.so
libgio-2.0.so.0
libgio-2.0.so.0.5000.3
libglib-2.0.so
libglib-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0.5000.3
```

Basically, I want to know the unique name/address of the object `/org/bluez/hci0` located on the system bus using gdbus library. Does anyone have an example of how I would do this using the C library?

Right now I can use the command

```
# dbus-monitor --system
```

To figure out that the address I need is `:1.22`. I'm almost certain that there's a better way to find the address then parsing the text output of that command.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the well-known name of the service (and if you want to keep track of the current unique owner, use g_bus_watch_name() to get it). In fact, I don't think there's ever a reason to find "/org/bluez/hci0" as you should be using D-Bus ObjectManager API to find the objects/interfaces that bluez exports

Comment: @jku This is the correct answer. If I look here https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt?h=5.44 I can see the well known name (service name). As this is my first time working with DBus I didn't realize that service name and well known name were the same thing. Post your comment below and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the well-known name of the service to find it (and if you want to keep track of the current unique owner, use `g_bus_watch_name()` to get it).

In fact, in the case of bluez I don't think there's ever a reason to search for "/org/bluez/hci0" as you should be using D-Bus ObjectManager API to find the objects/interfaces that the bluez service exports.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify some of the concepts here:

- **D-Bus address**: There is no such thing as an ‘address’ in D-Bus in the way you’re thinking. There are *object paths*, *well-known names* and *unique names*. The term ‘address’ is used to describe the socket path which clients use to connect to the dbus-daemon, but this is unrelated to what you’re asking.
- **Unique name**: Like `:1.22`, this uniquely identifies a particular connection to the dbus-daemon. Typically, each application has one connection to the daemon, so this typically identifies a single application. (However, applications can have more than one connection to the bus if they want; if so, each connection would have a different unique address). A **well-known name** is a consistent name for a service’s connection to the dbus-daemon, which is used as an alias for its unique name. For example, `org.bluez` or `org.freedesktop.FileManager1` are both well-known names.
- **Object address**: Like `/org/freedesktop/SomeService/blah`, this is actually called an *object path*. Object paths are only unique within the context of a single D-Bus connection, so the path `/a/b/c` will typically refer to different objects for D-Bus connections `:1.1` and `:1.2`. (Hence the question “how can I find the unique name of the object path `/a/b/c`?” is ill-formed, because there may be many unique names which export such an object.)